# IE7 and list-style-image alignment issues

Tags: css, xhtml, internet-explorer-7

I have a list that uses `list-style-image` and the list image is all over the place; I can't just add padding because the lines vary on size depending on the lines of text.

You can see the list on the bottom right of the page here: http://www.condorstudios.com/stuff/temp/index.php

I suppose I could create it as a background of the list item instead and pad the content; but are there any other options before I decide to change how it's coded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, list-style-image is problematic cross-browser. Use the image as a background image instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe support for this is null in IE7:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp

You could use :before or better still just make a background image.